# App Crashes with Segmentation Fault when using mysimplebook->GetPageCount() wxWidgets

Tags: c++, c++11, events, event-handling, wxwidgets

Hi i am using wxWidgets to create a simple app. But the example app(shown below) crashes when you click on black button on the screen. The app crashes only when you add the statement `mySimplebook->GetPageCount()` from inside the onClick() event handler. If i remove the use of the above statement from inside onClick() then the app does not crash. Also the use of the above statement in the MySimplebook constructor also does not crashes the app. The program only crashes when i use `mySimplebook->GetPageCount();` inside the onClick() handler. Otherwise, if you omit this statement from inside the onClick() handler the program works fine. The complete reproducible code that i have is as follows:

**mysimplebook.cpp**

```
MySimplebook::MySimplebook(wxFrame *m_parentWindow, int id): wxPanel(m_parentWindow, id)
{
    wxBoxSizer *mainBoxsizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    CustomButton *button = new CustomButton(this, wxID_ANY);
    mainBoxsizer->Add(button, 1, wxEXPAND, 0);
    mySimplebook = new wxSimplebook(this, wxID_ANY);

    First_Page *firstPage = new First_Page(mySimplebook);
    mySimplebook->AddPage(firstPage, "Input", false);
    
    mainBoxsizer->Add(mySimplebook, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
    /*program doesn't crashes here*/
    std::cout<<"Pages inside constructor: "<<(mySimplebook->GetPageCount())<<std::endl;
    this->SetSizer(mainBoxsizer);
}
void MySimplebook::onClick(wxMouseEvent &event)
{
    std::cout<<"event received from button"<<std::endl;
    //program creashes here
    std::cout<<"pagecount inside onclick:"<<(mySimplebook->GetPageCount())<<std::endl;
}
```

**custombutton.cpp**

```
CustomButton::CustomButton(wxWindow *parent, int id):wxPanel(parent, id)
{
    SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(0,0,0));
    Connect(wxEVT_LEFT_UP, wxMouseEventHandler(MySimplebook::onClick));
    
}
```

The program crashes when i click on the button. My questions are:

1. How can i resolve this runtime crash?
2. Why does this crash happen? How should i avoid it in the future like using the `bind`. Or which part of my code should be changed and how?

This is the traceback:
[image: traceback]

The program crashes with the following on the console:

```
Pages inside constructor: 1
event received from button
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

PS: I know the problem is most probably with the `Connect()` call. But don't know how to resolve/correct it.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but you need to share `AddPage` implementation and also https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_notebook.html

Comment: It's kind of hard to say anything without a proper [mcve]. Also, have you tried to use a debugger to catch the crash to verify it happens where you believe it happens?

Comment: @macroland AddPage() is a predefined method. It is not a custom method that i have written. How can i share the implementation file of AddPage()? Can you be more clear?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have attached the traceback as screenshot.

Comment: In the `MySimplebook` constructor, what is the value of `this`? What is the value of `this` in the `onClick` function when the crash happens? What is the value of `mySimplebook` in the constructor and in the `onClick` function? Have any of the values changed?

Comment: Opps sorry, I read it as `MySimplebook`.

Comment: @JasonLiam, it would help everybody if you post the text version of everything and not a screenshot. Some people are blind, but still can help with the questions. Also it doersn't help the cause to ask the same questions on 3 different resources at the same time. Please cosnsider doing it at one place only (starting with forum or here) and when asked - post it to the other place. It just kills your reputation online (and here).

Comment: @JasonLiam, you need to provide an `event sink` parameter to the `Connect()` call. Please check the documentation and make an appropriate change,.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude as you suggested, i checked the value of "this" in both MySimplebook constructor and inside onClick() function. And it looks like the value is changed. The value of "this" inside constructor is: `$1 = (MySimplebook * const) 0x555555dac800` while inside the onClick() "this" has value: `$2 = (MySimplebook * const) 0x555555ee7540` . How is the value changed and how can i prevent this from changing?

Comment: That `this` changes indicates that your object is copied somewhere and that the `onClick` call is done on the copy. Part of the copying could also lead to the *destruction* of objects, and you need to check your destructors to make sure it doesn't `delete` anything it should not delete. And you should take care to follow [the rules of three, five or zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem seems to be that the "this" pointer is copied to the `wxWindow parent` parameter when i create the CustomButton usin `CustomButton *button = new CustomButton(this, wxID_ANY);`. Now the value of the parent parameter is different from our original "this" pointer. Now when the control flow goes to onClick() handler the value of `parent` is taken  as thevalue of "this" pointer and not the original valueof "this". Can you tell if this problem can be resolved easily or i should create a CustomEvent Class sothat customevent can propagate upwards and avoid this problem?

Comment: @jasonliam, you shouldn't expect people to write code for you. This is not what SO is. What I did is to point out that you code had a problem and I indicated what the problem is. Next I would expect you to check the docs and understand why the code you posted have the problem and fix it. Whether you use Connect() or Bind() doesn't really matter. Bind() will warn you. Connect() will crash.

Comment: BTW,  reputation is important. Especially on this site. It gives you more privileges and possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `bind` instead of `connect`. Instead of using the Connect() call from inside custombutton.cpp we can just use `bind` right after that button is created inside the mysimplebook.cpp. So after changing the statement:

```
Connect(wxEVT_LEFT_UP, wxMouseEventHandler(MySimplebook::onClick));
```

to

```
button->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP, &MySimplebook::onClick, this);
```

the program works. Note that the bind statement is just after the definition of the CustomButton inside mysimplebook.cpp and there is no need to use it inside the custombutton constructor.

Comment: Using `Bind()` is indeed better and less error-prone than using `Connect()` but you still need to understand that you've used `Connect()` wrongly because you didn't provide it with `MySimplebook` pointer that it needs to call its `onClick()` method instead of just seemingly saying that "oh, Connect doesn't work".

Comment: Yeah, i figured that out too. The problem with the real project that i am working on is that the class MySimplebook has `#include"custombutton.h"` and class Custombutton has `#include"mysimplebook.h"` so it results in cyclic dependency. I changed the structure of the project like now the class Custombutton has no dependency on class MySimplebook. I guess, due to this change in structure i could still use Connect() but this time by also passing the pointer to MySimplebook to the Connect call. But Bind() is more modern C++ oriented so i will use bind as i am already using other C++ 11 features.